# sbt fails to download jna-4.1.0.jar Connection reset

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.5

I have a new SBT/Scala setup with an existing Play/Scala project. When I try and run `activator clean` in the folder, I get the error below:

```
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna
-4.1.0.jar ...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0!jna.jar: Connection reset (1178
4ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0!jna.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.
1.0/jars/jna.jar
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/net.java.dev.jn
a/jna/4.1.0/jars/jna.jar
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\4.1.0\jars\jna.
jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar

[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Projects\xxxxxxxxxxxx\repository\net.java.dev.j
na\jna\4.1.0\jars\jna.jar
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/
jna-4.1.0.jar
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.
1.0/jars/jna.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0!jna.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0!jna.jar
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet
ries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:
97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1439)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1435)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1
470)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1
468)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1473)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1467)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1490)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1417)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22
8)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22
8)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: net.java.dev.jna#jna;4
.1.0!jna.jar
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

If I try and paste the URL `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar` for the jar in my browser, I am able to download the jar. 
I tried to delete both .sbt and .ivy folders and then ran the command again, but got the same error.

Not sure what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

***Update***
I ran the build from activator UI and enabled debug output. Here is what I found:

Activator first tries to download `https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.1.0/jars/jna.jar`

which really does not exist. Copy and paste the URL in a browser, and it says not found.

It then tries `https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.1.0/jars/jna.jar` and fails for the same reason.

It then tries `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar` which succeeds and it starts to download, but fails with the error below:

```
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar ...
    public: downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar
[warn]  [FAILED     ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0!jna.jar: Connection reset (22821ms)
    [FAILED     ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0!jna.jar: Connection reset (22821ms)
        tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar
        tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.1.0/jars/jna.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.1.0/jars/jna.jar
```

Not sure whats causing that `connection reset`?

**UPDATE 2:** It turns out that the jar in question, has a DLL file in it. I'm wondering if it is the Netscaler/Antivirus that is causing the issue. Have logged a call with the Network admins.

Comment: Are you perhaps working behind a proxy/firewall?

Comment: Yes I am. I added the custom/self signed certificate to the cacerts used by the proxy to the underlying JVM and it was able to download all other JAR's, but that particular jar fails.

Answer (score 0):

I can get information that you did not set the `Local Maven Repository` as one of your repositories which means your sbt project will not search the dependency in your local maven repository which is a place that storing your maven dependency jars. If your sbt project can not download the jar from internet by itself. You can give a help by doing the following things:

First, add the following statement in your build.sbt

```
resolvers += ("Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")
```

Second, download the dependency jar by yourself from maven repository. As for your question, the download link is [there](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar)

Then, publish the jar to your local maven repository by using the following command assuming that the jar file is in the directory `~`

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=~/jna-4.1.0.jar -DgroupId=net.java.dev.jna -DartifactId=jna -Dversion=4.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Lastly, refresh your sbt project.

if you find `mvn command not found`, please install it.

A [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286669/adding-mongodb-to-sbt-in-a-java-only-project/37318087#37318087) which I gived answer to another question may help you.

Good luck